# Formula for calculating camera x,y,z position to force 3D point to appear at left side of the screen and rightmost position on the globe

Tags: math, 3d, camera, geometry

I'd need a formula to calculate 3D position and direction or orientation of a camera in a following situation:

Camera starting position is looking directly into center of the Earth. Green line goes straight up to the sky

[image]

Position that camera needs to move to is looking like this

[image]

Starting position probably shouldn't matter, but the question is:
How to calculate camera position and direction given 3D coordinates of any point on the globe. In the camera final position, the distance from Earth is always fixed. From desired camera point of view, the chosen point should appear at the rightmost point of a globe.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want for camera position is a point on the intersection of a plane parallel to the tangent plane at the location, but somewhat further from the Center, and a sphere representing the fixed distance the camera should be from the center. The intersection will be a circle, so there are infinitely many camera positions that work.

Camera direction will be 1/2 determined by the location and 1/2 determined by how much earth you want in the picture.

Suppose (0,0,0) is the center of the earth, Re is the radius of the earth, and (a,b,c) is the location on the earth you want to look at. If it's in terms of latitude and longitude you should convert to Cartesian coordinates which is straightforward. Your camera should be on a plane perpendicular to the vector (a,b,c) and at a height k*Re above the earth where k>1 is some number you can adjust. The equation for the plane is then ax+by+cz=d where d = k*Re^2. Note that the plane passes through the point (ka,kb,kc) in space, which is what we wanted.

Since you want the camera to be at a certain height above the earth, say h*Re where 1 < k < h, you need to find points on ax+by+cz=d for which x^2+y^2+z^2 = h^2*Re^2. So we need the intersection of the plane and a sphere. It will be easier to manage if we have a coordinate system on the plane, which we get from an orthonormal system which includes (a,b,c). A good candidate for the second vector in the orthonormal system is the projection of the z-axis (polar axis, I assume). Projecting (0,0,1) onto (a,b,c),

```
proj_(a,b,c)(0,0,1) = (a,b,c).(0,0,1)/|(a,b,c)|^2 (a,b,c)
= c/Re^2 (a,b,c)
```

Then the "horizontal component" of (0,0,1) is

```
u = proj_Plane(0,0,1) = (0,0,1) - c/Re^2 (a,b,c) 
= (-ac/Re^2,-bc/Re^2,1-c^2/Re^2)
```

You can normalize the vector to length 1 if you wish but there's no need. However, you do need to calculate and store the square of the length of the vector, namely

```
|u|^2 = ((ac)^2 + (bc)^2 + (Re^2-c^2))/Re^4
```

We could complicate this further by taking the cross product of (0,0,1) and the previous vector to get the third vector in the orthonormal system, then obtain a parametric equation for the intersection of the plane and sphere on which the camera lies, but if you just want the simplest answer we won't do that.

Now we need to solve for t such that

```
|(ka,kb,kc)+t(-ac/Re^2,-bc/Re^2,1-c^2/Re^2)|^2 = h^2 Re^2
|(ka,kb,kc)|^2 + 2t (a,b,c).u + t^2 |u|^2 = h^2 Re^2
```

Since (a,b,c) and u are perpendicular, the middle term drops out, and you have

```
t^2 = (h^2 Re^2 - k^2 Re^2)/|u|^2.
```

Substituting that value of t into

```
(ka,kb,kc)+t(-ac/Re^2,-bc/Re^2,1-c^2/Re^2)
```

gives the position of the camera in space.

As for direction, you'll have to experiment with that a bit. Some vector that looks like

```
(a,b,c) + s(-ac/Re^2,-bc/Re^2,1-c^2/Re^2)
```

should work. It's hard to say a priori because it depends on the camera magnification, width of the view screen, etc. I'm not sure offhand whether you'll need positive or negative values for s. You may also need to rotate the camera viewport, possibly by 90 degrees, I'm not sure.

If this doesn't work out, it's possible I made an error. Let me know how it works out and I'll check.

Comment: I use Cartesian coordinate system. Around 1/7 of the screen should be Earth, but doesn't have to be exactly. The circle, it probably doesn't really matter, I'd prefer simplest calculation